# How to get Jenkins to just perform 'git fetch' on a Bitbucket Git repo whenever ANY change is pushed to it

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I'd like to setup a Jenkins job that just performs a '`git fetch`' on a Bitbucket/Git repository every time a change is pushed to the repository. Is there any way to do it without Jenkins going into a "`seen branch xxx`" and it forking a new job to checkout that particular branch.

Right now, I have configured my Jenkins job to "build" a bunch of git branches - specified with wildcards - but Jenkins keeps doing the "`seen branch xxx`" and forking new job thing for each and every branch.

Assuming I setup bitbucket to send notifications to Jenkins via the post-commit hooks, is there a way to get Jenkins to only perform "git fetch", instead of checking out the source code for the branch for which the push was made to?